# OSError. locateOnScreen not working in pyautogui

Tags: python, png, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.locateOnScreen('photo.png')
```

> Error: OSError: Failed to read photo.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

Comment: Make sure `photo.png` is in the same directory as the script.

Comment: or use `/full/path/to/photo.png`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the development environment, it does not see 'photo.png'. Must be run from command line.

Comment: But for convenience, I would like to continue using the terminal in IDE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).