# Pyautogui failed to read

Tags: python, pyautogui

It said that the file I referenced did not exist even though it was in the same directory. I do not understand what have gone wrong. Did it stop supporting the newest python?

````
import pyautogui

print("started")

time.sleep(3)

#hello = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('TEST.png')

pyautogui.click('hello.png')```

```[ WARN:0@3.681] global /Users/xperience/actions-runner/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('hello.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrewzhuang/Programming/Python/Autogrinder/Autogrind Advanced.py", line 10, in <module>
    pyautogui.click('hello.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 980, in click
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 661, in _normalizeXYArgs
    location = locateOnScreen(firstArg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 353, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 207, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 170, in _load_cv2
    raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
OSError: Failed to read hello.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569671/oserror-locateonscreen-not-working-in-pyautogui

Comment: Pillow needs to be installed, and on Linux you may need to install additional libraries to make sure Pillow's PNG/JPEG works correctly.